# Split DataFrame value into multiple columns while saving to excel?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I have a requirement of changing the dataframe single column to multiple columns and store in excel.

### Example#

in DataFrame df I have values like

```
tp = [["'Attribute1', 143040, 'YES', '     143040', '          100.000000', '          0', 0, '-', '-', '-', '-'"],
["'Attribute2', 143040, 'YES', '     143040', '          100.000000', '          0', 0, '-', '-', '-', '-'"],
["'Attribute3', 143040, 'YES', '     143040', '          100.000000', '          0', 0, '-', '-', '-', '-'"]]

s = pd.DataFrame(tp)
s.columns = ['column_two']
print(s)

                                          column_two
0  'Attribute1', 143040, 'YES', '     143040', '     ...
1  'Attribute2', 143040, 'YES', '     1...
2  'Attribute3', 143040, 'YES', '     143040', '     ...
```

All the above values are stored at single index 0 in a DataFrame.

I need to split the above such that each value goes in a single column.
I mean the excel should be saved as below in separate columns  #

```
'Attribute1', 143040, 'YES', ' 143040', ' 100.000000', ' 0', 0, '-', '-', '-', '-'
```

Please help me as I am unable to

Comment: `s['column_two'].str.split(', ', expand=True)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd 
tp = [["'Attribute1', 143040, 'YES', '     143040', '          100.000000', '          
0', 0, '-', '-', '-', '-'"],
["'Attribute2', 143040, 'YES', '     143040', '          100.000000', '          0',0, 
'-', '-', '-', '-'"],
["'Attribute3', 143040, 'YES', '     143040', '          100.000000', '          0',0, 
'-', '-', '-', '-'"]]

#SPLITTING INTO MULTIPLE COLUMNS 
s =s.column_two.str.split(',', expand= True)

print(s)
        0        1       2               3   ...    7     8     9     10
0  'Attribute1'   143040   'YES'   '     143040'  ...   '-'   '-'   '-'   '-'
1  'Attribute2'   143040   'YES'   '     143040'  ...   '-'   '-'   '-'   '-'
2  'Attribute3'   143040   'YES'   '     143040'  ...   '-'   '-'   '-'   '-'

#STORING AS EXCEL FILE
s.to_excel(r'H:\your_dataframe.xlsx', index = False)
```